# SIGSTOP signal everytime i run my program for named pipe in linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, signals, named-pipes

I have a program for checking if pipe exist or not so wrote this in a function :

```
status = mkfifo("recv",0666);
fd1 = open("recv",O_WRONLY);
fd2 = open("sendd", O_RDONLY);
cout<<"we are checking botth bcz we have both read and write in the program------:)";
if(fd1 <0 && fd2 <0)
{
    //strerror(errno);
    err = 1;// a const for remote
}
else if(fd1 >0 || fd2 >0){
    err = 2; // a const for local
}
else{
    err = 3; // a const for progrm failure error
    cout<<"program has some problems";
}
```

But everytime i run my program it stops at fd1 = open("recv",O_WRONLY); saying Thread1: signal SIGSTOP although it works correctly with just fd2= open("sendd", O_RDONLY);  I dont know why its giving this error?? i am new to pipes in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM, http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

> Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary file. However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.